# How to write Electron debug messages into a file?

Tags: debugging, logging, electron

I am developing an Electron app and I want to write it's debug messages into a log file. If I start my app by executing `electron electron --debug=5858`, then the debug output shows up in my console.

I can grab the console output from the command-line by attaching `> debug.log` to my cmd statement but I wonder if there is also a programmatic way to save the debug logs for [Electron's main process](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/debugging-main-process.md)?

My main goal is to be able to write debug logs from the main process when distributing my app.